# Will my data partition will be wiped off on reinstall if I mount it under home directory?

Tags: partitioning

Here is my partitioning scheme at the time of install

```
/dev/sda1 mount at /
/dev/sda2 is swap
/dev/sda3 #it it not mounted at the time of install, going to be a separate data partition
```

after installation, I mounted `/dev/sda3` under `/home/myusername/data` and edited `fstab` file so that the the data partition is mounted automatically on boot.

My question is: will my data partition (i.e. `/dev/sda3`) wiped off if I make a re-install on this hard drive without formatting `/dev/sda3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer No.

If you just format and reinstall Ubuntu in `/dev/sda1` without touching `/dev/sda3` your data partition will remain unaltered.

Only you have to mount the partition `/dev/sda3` properly to access those data in it.